# GIMP 2.8 themes aren't applying after I select them

Tags: 13.04, themes, gimp, gtk-2

I want apply themes to GIMP 2.8

In particular I want it to look like Photoshop (now at least)

I tried putting in a GTK2 theme in the themes folder under .gimp in my home and placing the gtkrc file under the same themes folder... The themes do list out in the list under theme preferences but they don't get applied...(I did restart gimp)

What's possibly wrong?

Comment: If you dont mind my asking, where did you get this theme?

Comment: Some GTK+ themes require a theme engine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you place the theme folder within ~/.themes so you can pick them as a general theme as well. When using the theme only for a single application, it does not matter where you place them, but you might as well place them in the usual place.

If you open a terminal window and run the following command, you can see that it will open the application with the specified theme:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/your/theme/gtkrc gimp
```

Of course, you need to replace `/path/to/your/theme/gtkrc` with the path to the `gtkrc` file, which is located in the `gtk-2.0` folder of the theme.

Now, you don't want to have to run a terminal command every time you want to start the Gimp. Luckily, we can edit the command executed when we start the Gimp, as follows.

This command is defined in the .desktop file. Since we want to run Gimp in this theme for the current user, we first have to copy the first system-wide .desktop file to our user directory. This can be done with the following terminal command:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

(Note that you might have to create the folder `/home/vincent/.local/share/applications` first if it does not exist yet.)

Next, we edit the new file:

```
 gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gimp.desktop
```

Here, you can see a line that starts with `Exec=` followed by the command to run the Gimp. Simply prefix that command by `GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/your/theme/gtkrc` and save the file. Next time you run the Gimp, it will be in your dark theme!